# Loading navigation properties after an insert

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having issues retrieving navigation properties after an insert.

Here's a working example when navigation properties are properly populated:

```
var entities = Context.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id == myId).ToList();

//entities[0].MyNavProp is populated here...
```

The problem is after an insert....

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity 
              {
                //all properties properly filled, no error in insert....
              };

Context.MyEntity.Add(myEntity);

Context.SaveChanges();

//here, myEntity's navigation properties are null.... :(
```

Here's what I've tried

```
Context.SaveChanges();
Context.Attach(myEntity);
Context.Entry(myEntity).Reload();
myEntity = Context.MyEntity.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == theId);
```

Still, navigation properties are null.

I am using `UseLazyLoadingProxies` in my `Startup` set up.

If I do a simple query against the database in a separate request, like so

```
var result = Context.MyEntity.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 31);
```

I get an entity of type `Castle.Proxies.MyEntityProxy` but when doing the same query right after the insert, I get an entity of type `MyEntity`.

Looks like the proxy lazy loading feature isn't working in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out the solution for now is creating an explicit proxy.

Replace

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity 
{
    //all properties properly filled, no error in insert....
};
```

By

```
var myEntity = Context.MyEntity.CreateProxy();
//populate entities, add to context and SaveChanges()....
```

Your navigation properties will be populated correctly, at least in my case they were.

Comment: The best answer for me!

Answer (score 2):

`UseLazyLoadingProxies` requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual navigation properties, and have a public or protected constructor.

Another important point to attention is not to use `AsNoTracking()` when recovering entity from your context, using `UseLazyLoadingProxies`.

I reproduced a similar scenery, and it's worked correctly for me.

Implementation details:

`Thing` entity (*something like a child aggregate*):

```
public class Thing : Entity<Guid>
{
    internal Thing(Guid id, string name, string type, double value)
    {
        SetId(id);
        SetName(name);
        SetType(type);
        SetValue(value);
    }

    // The default constructor must be explicitly defined, 
    // for use Lazy Loading Proxies.
    protected Thing() { }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public double Value { get; private set; }

    // Setters commented for brevity
}
```

`Whatever` entity (*root aggregate*):

```
public class Whatever : Entity<Guid>
{
    internal Whatever(Guid id, string name, DateTime time, string type)
    {
        SetId(id);
        SetName(name);
        SetTime(time);
        SetType(type);
        Things = new List<Thing>();
    }

    // The default constructor must be explicitly defined, 
    // for use Lazy Loading Proxies.
    protected Whatever() { }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    //Virtual navigation required
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; }
    public DateTime Time { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    // Setters commented for brevity
}
```

Entity type configuration:

```
public class WhateverConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Whatever>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Whatever> builder)
    {
        // commented for brevity
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Things);
    }
}
```

IoC:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, Action<RepositoriesOptions> options)
{
    options.Invoke(RepositoriesOptions);

    return services.AddDbContext<WhateverContext>(dbContextOptions
        => dbContextOptions.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlite(RepositoriesOptions.ConnectionString, sqliteOptions
                => sqliteOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(WhateverContext).Assembly.GetName().Name)));
}
```

Repository:

```
public virtual async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (await ExistsAsync(entity.Id, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) return;

    await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);
}
```

Service:

```
public async Task<TEntity> SaveAsync(TModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
    if (entity.IsValid) await _repository.InsertAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
    return entity;
}
```

The `entity` returned from the service after saving:

[image: result]

Versions used:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.3" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I hope it helps you in some way.

Comment: This is an _exceptionally_ well documented answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution

After calling `SaveChanges()` execute following code:

```cs
IList<EntityEntry> entries = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
foreach (EntityEntry e in entries)
{
    e.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
}
```

after setting statuses we have to read our top level Model item from DbSet via `First(item => item.Id == id)/FirstOrDefault()` or using other method

where:

- ChangeTracker is a property of DbContext.
- EntityEntry is defined in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking

My Ef Core version is:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
```